# time-dependent vector field chain rule

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Consider the time dependent vector field **F** related to some vector field **B** by **F**(**x**, $t)=$**B**(t**x**). I am asked to prove $\displaystyle(x \cdot \nabla){\bf F}=t\frac{\partial {\bf F}}{\partial t}$.

---

I'm not sure how **F** being related to **B** helps proving the result which involves only **F**. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

\begin{eqnarray}
({\bf x}\cdot \nabla){\bf F}({\bf x}, t) &=& \sum_{k}x_k \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}{\bf F}({\bf x}, t) = \sum_{k,l}x_k \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\hat{e}_l F_l({\bf x}, t) \\
&=& \sum_{k,l}x_k \hat{e}_l\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}B_l(t{\bf x}) = \sum_{k,l}x_k \hat{e}_lB_l'(t{\bf x})~t\tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

On the other hand

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial }{\partial t} {\bf F}({\bf x}, t) &=&\sum_{l}\hat{e}_l \frac{\partial }{\partial t}F_l({\bf x}, t)= \sum_{l} \hat{e}_l \frac{\partial }{\partial t}B_l(t{\bf x}) \\
&=& \sum_{k,l} \hat{e}_l B_l'(t{\bf x}) x_k \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Which means that

$$
({\bf x}\cdot \nabla){\bf F}({\bf x}, t) = 
\frac{\partial }{\partial t} {\bf F}({\bf x}, t)
$$